# sql server nested cursor not returning results

Tags: t-sql, cursor, nested

My first nested cursor 'uncalcdays' is not returning data.  The first (un-nested) cursor 'codes' is returning correct data, and is passing this data correctly to the variable @codes.

If I cut the sql from uncalcdays and run in separate query window it returns data.
If I cut the sql from 'codes' and 'uncalcday', create appropriate varialbes and run in a separate query window, they both return correct data.

This is doing my head in!  Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong..?

The plan is that I need to identify the first master record that does not have child data (i.e. master record with lowest id that has no child records.)  It's been a while since I've used sql server, be gentle.

Rgds
Dave

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @code nvarchar(10)
declare @id numeric
declare @val numeric
declare @total numeric
declare @count numeric
declare @avg numeric
declare @fetch_codes int
declare @fetch_uncalcdays int
declare @fetch_twentyvals int

-- get a list of codes
declare codes cursor for 
    select distinct code from dbo.EOD_Data;

-- get a list of the days that are unprocessed
declare uncalcdays cursor for 
    select d.id
        from dbo.EOD_Data d
             left outer join dbo.EOD_Computed_Stats cs
             on d.id = cs.EOD_Data_Id
       where cs.SMA_20D is null
         and d.CODE = @code
       order by d.id asc; 

-- get the last 20d data for a given stock code
declare twentyvals cursor for 
    select top(20) d.id 
    from dbo.EOD_Data d
    where d.id <= @id
      and d.code = @code
    order by d.id desc;

-- loop through stock codes
open codes
fetch next from codes
    into @code
select @fetch_codes = @@FETCH_STATUS

while @fetch_codes = 0
begin

    open uncalcdays
    fetch next from uncalcdays
      into @id
    select @fetch_uncalcdays = @@FETCH_STATUS

    while @fetch_uncalcdays = 0
    begin

        -- loop through the twenty most recent close prices and calc average
        open twentyvals
        fetch next from twentyvals
            into @val
        select @fetch_twentyvals = @@FETCH_STATUS

        while @fetch_twentyvals = 0
        begin

            ...stuff

        fetch next from uncalcdays
            into @id
        select @fetch_uncalcdays = @@FETCH_STATUS

    end

    close uncalcdays
    deallocate uncaldays

fetch next from codes
    into @code
select @fetch_codes = @@FETCH_STATUS

end

close codes
deallocate codes
```

END

Comment: Debug one cursor at a time. Set outter cursor values to a contant and make the inner most one to work. Then debug 2nd and 1st levels in the same manner. Also you need to `close` and `deallocate` cursor: `twentyvals`.

Comment: I'm not sure how that SQL runs at all. Shouldn't the inner cursors be declared within the appropriate loop so that the variables are populated?

Answer (score 0):

cursors are cool to code and troubleshoot, they can be very helpful, but please try this code instead, it works of sets of stocks rather of individual record at a time:

```
    --STEP 1 - Get list of unprocessed stocks
    SELECT d.Code
    INTO #unprocessedCodes
    FROM dbo.EOD_Data d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EOD_Computed_Stats cs
            ON d.id = cs.EOD_Data_Id
    WHERE cs.SMA_20D IS NULL 

    --STEP 2 - Rate the data base on the date id
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY d.Code, d.id ASC) AS RowNumber,
        d.Price,  --it is good if you have closed price in the table, 
                  --otherwise you would add a join
        d.id AS DateID, 
        d.Code
    INTO #PricingChart
    FROM dbo.EOD_Data d
        INNER JOIN #unprocessedCodes uc
            ON d.Code = uc.Code

    --STEP 3 - Get average of first 20 prices for all unprocessed codes 
    SELECT 
        Code,
        AVG(Price) AS AvgPrice 
    FROM #PricingChart
    WHERE RowNumber <= 20 --you only interested in top 20
    GROUP BY Code
```

i tried to stay as close to your tables as possible, this is not perfect, but it might be faster than looping though the many records in the cursor.